# Understanding Make rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is an example that I found online

```
all: test

test: test.c
    gcc test.c -o test
```

I understand that `test.c` is a pre requisite, but since there was no path defined where `test.c` is, does this mean that `test.c` is expected to be in the current directory?

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: It is also valid to have `test: ../srcs/test.c`.  I.e., you can use paths to the prerequisites.  If you do so, there is a lot of value in using the automatic variables that LethalProgrammer points out in his answer below.  There are also lots of tricks in Make for making lists of files, then using built-in list-processing functions to prepend the relevant paths---but you can look into those once you get the basics.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question, yes that is already answered @Rafael.

test.c expected to be in that current directory or else it will end up in error.

---

I'm adding more pedagogic information to understand the basic Makefile.

**This is the simple makefile looks, [Introduction makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction).**

```
target … : prerequisites …
        recipe
        …
        …
```

1. Target is the name of file generated by your program and the it can also the name of an action such as clean.
2. Prerequisite is a file that is used as input to create the target. A target often depends on several files.
3. The recipe is an action that `make` carries out. A recipe may have more than one command, either on the same line or each on its own line. Please note: you need to put a tab character at the beginning of every recipe line

---

**Something more advanced, [Writing recipes with directory search.](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recipes_002fSearch.html#Recipes_002fSearch)**

When a prerequisite is found in another directory through directory search, this cannot change the recipe of the rule; they will execute as written. Therefore, you must write the recipe with care so that it will look for the prerequisite in the directory where make finds it.

**$^: [Automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables):**

```
foo.o : foo.c
        cc -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```